# Scala disk based Map

Tags: scala, caching, hashmap, redis, key-value

I have a large map that won't fit in memory and I thus want it to live on the disk. I have the following options:

1. Use a pure Java library like [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB): This works but I don't get Scala
   collections sugar like `getOrElseUpdate` and `++=` and the
   `apply`/`update` methods. I could create my own wrapper class around `MapDB` in Scala but I really don't want to manually implement all the `Map` traits.
2. Use something like redis/memcached: I could not find a good scala library that gave me the `Map` traits for redis or memcached. This may be the better performance solution but it introduces a complexity of running a db

So is there any nice scala only library that implements the Scala collection sugars for maps and yet it falls back on disk and/or a key-value store for large maps?

Comment: It looks like the implementations extend [`java.util.AbstractMap<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html) which implements `Map<K,V>` - it seems like there should be a generic wrapper/bridge around Java's `Map<K,V>` that could be used. And, if one can't be used, why not? :D

Comment: e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027868/how-to-convert-from-from-java-util-map-to-a-scala-map

Comment: The question is generalized: How to access `java.util.Map<K,V>` as `scala.mutable.Map[K,V]`? I did a search for `java map scala immutable.map` and was rewarded with http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worth mentioning [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map): it's basically the same thing as MapDB (disk-persisted `ConcurrentMap` implementation), but it's [much more efficient](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#benchmarks) than MapDB.

Example:

```
val cache: mutable.Map[String, java.util.List[String]] = ChronicleMap
    .of(classOf[String], classOf[java.util.List])
    .averageKey("key")
    .averageValue(...)
    .valueMarshaller(ListMarshaller.of(
        CharSequenceBytesReader.INSTANCE,
        CharSequenceBytesWriter.INSTANCE
    ))
    .entries(...)
    .createPersistedTo(file)
```

Answer (score 7):

Answered my own question

```
import collection.mutable
import org.mapdb.DBMaker
import collection.JavaConversions._

val cache: mutable.Map[String, Seq[String]] = DBMaker.newTempHashMap[String, Seq[String]]()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `val cache: collection.concurrent.Map[String, Seq[String]]` to have access to concurrent methods like `putIfAbsent`?